# GOCD - force email notification on failed build/test

Tags: go-cd, thoughtworks-go

Is there a way to "force" the email notification setting on all users so that if they make a change that causes a build/test to fail in one of our pipelines?

I've read the documentation of the email notification that's available (link below) but is there a way to set this setting for all users (including future users) ?

link to GoCD email notification doc: https://docs.gocd.org/current/configuration/dev_notifications.html

Comment: Have you seen the plugin linked from the "supported plugins" page? I guess if you set a team e-mail address it could work. I don't really see how to finetune it for different pipelines though. https://www.gocd.org/plugins/

Comment: Yeah i took a look at this plugin: 
https://github.com/gocd-contrib/email-notifier which seems interesting, but i think this would still require a lot of maintenance of the emailing list. What i'm hoping for is just setting the email notification setting as "on" by default for all users

Comment: to clarify: I am trying to figure out if i can run a script that alters a config file somewhere to turn on the email notifications for all users on the server. I have looked at the config.xml of the GoCD server, but the email notification setting for each user doesn't seem to be recorded in there